# How to revert back to a process triggered by ssh?

Tags: ssh, ad-hoc-network

I am using some Raspberry Pi -2 and a Ubuntu Laptop (14.04 LTS) in ad-hoc fashion over WiFi. I have some `python3` scripts that I usually trigger using the `ssh -6` (since I am using **IPv6 Link-Local Addresses**) to trigger my python3 script.

For Example:

```
ssh -6 pi@fe80::a1b2:c3ff:fed4:e5g6%wlan0 'python3 myScript.py'
```

to kill the script on the socket I use:

```
ssh -6 pi@fe80::a1b2:c3ff:fed4:e5g6%wlan0 'fuser -k portNumber/udp'
```

This will trigger the script on the raspberry Pi and unless I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I will ofcourse see the output of the scripts on my terminal. But I am conducting some experiments where I usually escape the terminal and the script on the Pis is kept running (some socket programs!).

I want to return to the script on the Pi is it possible? I mean when I once again `ssh -6` to the pi's address can I actually go to the terminal where the process is still running? As far as I recall I cannot use the different `tty`s of the Pi while using `ssh`.

#### Note :

I am really not sure if I should post this here or on **ServerFault** please be kind enough to guide me!

Comment: `screen`, `tmux` might do what you want, but it is really hard to understand what you are trying to describe ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return to the same terminal with plain ssh (the pty gets destroyed as soon as ssh disconnects), and in fact there is *no* terminal when you run commands in "batch mode" – just raw stdout. (There's `-t` to force a terminal though.)

However, you can do this with terminal multiplexers like `tmux`, `screen`, or `dtach`, which are mostly written for this exact purpose:

```
ssh myserver "tmux new-session -d -n myscript ./myScript.py"

ssh -t myserver "tmux attach -n myscript"

ssh myserver "tmux kill-session -t myscript"
```

With dtach:

```
ssh myserver "dtach -n ~/myscript.sock ./myScript.py"

ssh -t myserver "dtach -a ~/myscript.sock"
```

With screen:

```
ssh myserver "screen -dmS myscript ./myScript.py"

ssh -t myserver "screen -r myscript"
```

Comment: Hi I need a quick tip for instance when I do the following: `tmux new-session -d -s mySession './myscript.py'` and when I attach using `tmux attach -t mySession`  I can see my script running. Now I want to get of out the session without stopping the script. I don't want to use `<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>` how can I use the Hotkeys in Tmux to safely exit the session without killing it. It should be something like `<kbd>CTRL</kbd>`+`<kbd>B</kbd>` then `<kbd>:</kbd>` and what more?

Comment: Ah ! nevermind found it! in the session i need `<kbd>ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>b</kbd>`+`<kbd>z</kbd>`

Comment: also the `ssh -t myserver "tmux a"` or `ssh -t myserver "tmux attach -t myscript"` gets me in the session but I can't then exit the command window of the `ssh` it gets stuck there